# How can i add jarsigner to the PATH

Tags: java, android, reactjs, native

i am trying make react-native application to .apk file. I have keystore file, but when i try

```
sudo ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

i got error message

```
"1 exception was raised by workers: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start "jarsigner" process, please add it to the PATH"
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: have you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

- This should be included within the bin folder of Java SDK.
  If you don't have the SDK installed, download it and install it, e.g:
  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

There is also a video on Youtube showing how to find it, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qtz88Vf0bdw